# Protect the SQLite database in PhoneGap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I have developed phoneGap application with database creation and i am able to access the database in every page by using instance of a database
    So here i do not know how to protect the database from others, because any body can access my database who knows the database name and version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      var db;
    // Populate the database
    function populateDB(tx) {
        alert('Table DEMO will be created');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, firstname, lastname)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (1, "Surinaidu", "Majji")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (2, "Sarath", "Upadrista")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (3, "Yaseen", "shaik")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (4, "Yogesh", "Tavaki")');
    }

    // Query the database
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var htmlString = '';
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("No of rows in the table " + len);

        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        htmlString += '<li>' + results.rows.item(i).id +  " " + results.rows.item(i).firstname + "  " + results.rows.item(i).lastname + '<br/>' + '</li>';
        }
        $('#listview').html(htmlString);
        // for an insert statement, this property will return the ID of the last inserted row
        console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert('successed');
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Database has been started");
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        alert(db);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="yellow">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.google.com" >Go to Google page</a>
    <ul id="listview"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same thing can be copied to other page and can access the data, i am thinking it is weired, because here many people downloads the same app with the same database instance,
        then how can we protect the one's data from another person.

Comment: `because any body can access my database who knows the database name and version` I'm not sure how other people will know about your database name and version. Many people are using this technique right!!

Comment: Yes you are right, but how do we differentiate one's data from others. imean every body can have their own identity right?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, A user of your software has more of a right to control the sqlite database than you do. Your software is just a visitor on his machine. Any form of encryption would be [security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) because you cannot have a secret (or secret key) on the device.

Finally, If you want to protect a database, then you have to host it. I recommend setting up a RESTFUL interface so that the js on the mobile device can perform actions on the data. You should assume that the attacker has 100% access to this RESTFUL interface. You should never expose a function like `do_query("select ...");`. Make sure you take sql injection into consideration. Let me know for any queries.

Comment: May i know what is sql injection here?